# mySQL update timestamp from 0

Tags: mysql

I have this mySQL syntax which updates the table `users` and column `skills_mod_time` every time the page is reloaded. `$sql = "UPDATE users SET skills_mod_time = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP";`

How can i change from instead of using the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to using a counting timestamp.
For example the column `skills_mod_time` is defaulted as `0`. If the page was reloaded 10 sec later, i want the seconds part to be 10. Instead of the current way where it changes `0` to this present time.

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` will always give the current timestamp. If you call it 10 seconds later, the timestamp will have advanced. What doesn't work as you need it to?

Comment: I have another column thats an `int` which increases by 1 every time another module is unlocked. A module is unlocked by time. If the `skills_mod_time` is greater than the set time, the `int` increases by one and the `skills_mod_time` is set back to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to log "seconds since login", or something similar, rather than "last activity."  To do this, you should create a column called `login_time`, or similar, and only update it when a user logs in.  You probably still want to track the last-activity time, as you do now, for the purpose of session expiry.

Then if you have these two columns, `login_time`, and `last_activity`, you can get the seconds between login_time and last_activity by subtracting the one from the other.  Or you can get the time since login by subtracting `login_time` from `NOW()`.

I hope this answers your question--if not, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

you can use timestampdiff function to take the difference of two timestamp values
something like 
UPDATE users SET skills_mod_time = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,skills_mod_time,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);